# Open HTML file in excel, preserving HTML inline styling

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to open a HTML file in excel (from VBA) so that the HTML inline styling is preserved. Are there any special ways of doing this because currently I've tried creating the HTML as a string and inserting into a cell using ActiveSheet.Range("A10") = HTMLStr but this isn't working and also when I open the file in Excel using:

Workbooks.Open

this also does not render the HTML correctly

(edit my final result is to turn the html into a pdf)

Comment: Copy-pasting HTML-formatted text is a bit finicky, and hoping that all formatting will be retained is probably over-optimistic. May we ask why you are trying to do this? There may be an alternative route...

Comment: You cant expect Excel to render HTML the same way as it supports only limited and old version of HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to open the page in Excel - is it just so you can make a PDF (Excel 2007/10) ?  You could try passing the HTML to IE and automating a copy/paste from there.

As an example, the following code will take a selection of cells with HTML, transfer each one to IE, then copy back the result.

```
Sub FormatHtmlViaIE()

Dim ie As Object, tr, c As Range

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    With ie

        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "about:blank"
        Do While .busy
        Loop

        For Each c In Selection
            .document.body.innerHTML = c.Value
            .document.body.createtextrange.execCommand "Copy"
            Selection.Parent.Paste Destination:=c
        Next c

        .Quit

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is, when I manually copy the IE-rendered HTML into Excel and paste as HTML, it doesn't display it correctly. Therefore, automating this copy-and-paste-from-IE process would result in the same?

Comment: Ok i have opened my HTML file in IE, pressed ctrl+A, then ctr+v in a new excel file, I clicked OK to the data size warning and it doesn't retain the HTML inline styling upon pasting...

Comment: Nothing at all?  Depending on how complex the styles are, you're not going to get all of them carried over: Excel is not a Web browser.  Howevber, you should see things like bold or text color etc.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise is open page in excel.

For Example

```
Sub OpenPage()
'officevb.com
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("http://www.stackoverflow.com")

wb.SaveAs "c:\Your\Path\Here\NameOfFile", xlWorkbookDefault

End Sub
```

[]'s

Comment: As the OP says, "[this doesn't work] when I open the file in Excel using: Workbooks.Open". I'm pretty sure the OP is trying to copy the formatted text, not the HTML code behind it.